# regex: plus sign vs asterisk

Tags: regex, grep

The asterisk or star tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token zero or more times. The plus tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token once or more.

Based on the definition, I was wondering why the plus sign returns more matches than the asterisk sign.

```
 echo "ABC ddd kkk DDD" | grep -Eo "[A-Z]+"
```

returns

ABC DDD

```
 echo "ABC ddd kkk DDD" | grep -Eo "[A-Z]*"
```

returns
ABC

Comment: Both print two lines for me: `ABC` followed by `DDD`. What version of `grep` are you using? If it's GNU grep, what's the output of `grep --version`? And please double-check the output of your second example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am using grep 2.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it doesn't. With GNU grep versions 2.5.3, 2.6.3, 2.10, and 2.12, I get:

```
$ echo "ABC ddd kkk DDD" | grep -Eo "[A-Z]+"
ABC
DDD
$ echo "ABC ddd kkk DDD" | grep -Eo "[A-Z]*"
ABC
DDD
```

Please double-check your second example. If you can confirm that you get only one line of output, it might be a bug in your `grep`. If you're using GNU `grep`, what's the output of `grep --version`? If not, what OS are you using, and (if you know) what `grep` implementation?

**UPDATE :**

I just built and installed GNU grep 2.5.1 (the version you're using) from source, and I confirm your output. It appears to be a bug in that version of `grep`, apparently corrected between 2.5.1a and 2.5.3. GNU grep 2.5.1 is about 12 years old; can you install a newer version? Looking through the `ChangeLog` for 2.5.3, I suspect this may have been the fix:

```
2005-08-24  Charles Levert  <charles_levert@gna.org>

    * src/grep.c (print_line_middle): In case of an empty match,
      make minimal progress and continue instead of aborting process
      of the remainder of the line, in case there's still an upcoming
      non-empty match.
    * tests/foad1.sh: Add two tests for this.
    * doc/grep.texi, doc/grep.1: Document this behavior, since
      --only-matching and --color are GNU extensions which are
      otherwise unspecified by POSIX or other standards.
```

Even if you don't have full access on the machine you're using, you should still be able to download the source tarball from `ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/` and install it under your home directory (assuming your system has a working compiler and associated tools).

Comment: I cannot install anything because it is not my machine, but thanks for confirming and letting me know. So it wasn't a knowledge problem after all but a bug. Thanks!

Comment: @Paolo: You should be able to install it from source under your home directory. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey Keith. I tried installing it under my home directory but I recieved many errors about permissions. 

test -z "/usr/local/share/info" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/info"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./grep.info '/usr/local/share/info'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/share/info/grep.info': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-info-am] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pco/grep/grep-2.9/doc'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pco/grep/grep-2.9/doc'

Comment: @Paolo: You have to specify the prefix where you want to install it: `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/whatever ; make ; make install`. And the latest version is 2.14; you might as well grab that.

Comment: Hey Keith, thanks for the answer. I did not know you could install it locally in your home drive. I dug deeper into the 'install' documentation to find out all about the prefix 'prefix'. Thanks again!

Comment: Keith another quick question. After I installed it, I still have the old grep 2.5.1. I think I'm suppose to source it or put it in my env path?

Comment: @Paolo: You can execute the newly installed `grep` either by specifying its full path or by adding the `../bin` directory to the front of your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Paolo Rereading this 7 years later, I see my previous comment might be misleading. I didn't mean literally `../bin`. You shouldn't generally have relative directory paths in your `$PATH`. For example, you might add `/home/yourname/local/bin` to your `$PATH`.