# Are (\w+)? and (\w*) the same?

Tags: regex

Is there any difference between `(\w+)?` and `(\w*)` in regex?
I don't understand if there is something that I am missing. I have used both in different codes but they seem to do exactly the same thing.
It's basically the same, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex: plus sign vs asterisk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364673/regex-plus-sign-vs-asterisk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- In terms of **what they are matching**, there's **no difference** between `(\w+)?` and `(\w*)`. They both match 0 or more occurrences of `\w`. This can be tested also by running a test with Perl's [Regexp-Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~vbar/Regexp-Compare-0.22/lib/Regexp/Compare.pm) module, which yielded the expected result.
- In terms of the **capturing group**, there's a **big difference**. In the case of `(\w+)?` if it fails, the capturing group is NOT initialized. In the case of `(\w*)` it will be initialized but will be empty. So in Perl `"!"=~/(\w+)?/; print $1;` will return a warning for $1 being undefined, while `"!"=~/(\w*)/; print $1;` an empty string.
- In terms of **performance**, the `(\w*)` must be ***slightly* better** in terms of the number of steps that the regular expression engine has to do and thus preferred. This depends on the engine of course. But with `(\w*)` the engine will never have to perform backtracking compared to `(\w+)?`.

  As an example I tried to use the `use re 'debug'` directive in Perl and compared the two regular expressions against an empty string. You can compare the steps for each of them:

`""=~/(\w+)?/`

```
Matching REx "(\w+)?" against ""
   0 <> <>                   |  1:CURLYX[0] {0,1}(10)
   0 <> <>                   |  9:  WHILEM(0)
                                    whilem: matched 0 out of 0..1
   0 <> <>                   |  3:    OPEN1(5)
   0 <> <>                   |  5:    PLUS(7)
                                      ALNUM can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
                                      failed...
                                    whilem: failed, trying continuation...
   0 <> <>                   | 10:    NOTHING(11)
   0 <> <>                   | 11:    END(0)

Match successful!
```

`""=~/(\w*)/`

```
Matching REx "(\w*)" against ""
   0 <> <>                   |  1:OPEN1(3)
   0 <> <>                   |  3:STAR(5)
                                  ALNUM can match 0 times out of 2147483647...
   0 <> <>                   |  5:  CLOSE1(7)
   0 <> <>                   |  7:  END(0)
Match successful!
```

PS. If you are not into Perl, I think that it is possible to debug regular expressions with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) too (I have never tried it, but I hear it a lot).

Comment: Conclusion: use `(\w*)`, not `(\w+)?` !

Answer (score 2):

> It's basically the same, right?

Yes. In your particular case. `(0 or 1) of (1 or more)` = `(0 or more)`.

Comment: "In your particular case", can you give a case where they are not the same?

Comment: Just wanting people to take care. I mean look at the regex carefully to see that your pattern applies (e.g. placement of braces etc. etc.). If it is confusing I can remove the comment.